# In Telerik's RadScheduler, the numbers on the top of each day have disappeared

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, telerik

I have a RadScheduler, the Date numbers that live in .rsDateHeader are no longer displaying. They exist when I inspect in Chrome, but aren't appearing on the page. Is anyone aware of a breaking change that may have affected this? I'm not seeing one in my research and it's driving me nuts!

Is there a field I can modify for this? Something in the CSS I can force?

Comment: On inspect, if you use `display:block;` on that element, does it then show like you want?

Comment: Sadly, it does not.

Comment: Okay, so I found a piece of CSS that seems to be the problem. under .RadScheduler .rsMonthView .rsWrap, the font-size is set to 0! I have no idea how this happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how it happened, as I'm the only one who would touch this, but I found a line in the CSS that set the font size to 0. If someone else is having this problem, make sure you thoroughly check any CSS that might touch this!